# How can I open a buffer in a new tab leaving the current window and buffer intact?

Tags: vim-windows, tabbed-user-interface

Often when coding I have this window layout - which is mapped to the flow of the program I am editing.

Tab1

```
+------------+--------------+
|            |              |
|            |      B       |
|            |              |
|            |              |
|  A         +--------------+
|            |              |
|            |              |
|            |       C      |
|            |              |
+------------+--------------+
```

Now I want to open `B` in a new tab to work on it, but I want to leave the layout of `tab1` intact.
Here is my desired outcome.

```
        tab1                         tab2
+------------+--------------+ +---------------------------+ 
|            |              | |                           | 
|            |      B       | |                           | 
|            |              | |                           | 
|            |              | |            B              | 
|  A         +--------------+ |                           | 
|            |              | |                           | 
|            |              | |                           | 
|            |       C      | |                           | 
|            |              | |                           | 
+------------+--------------+ +---------------------------+
```

#### What I have tried using vim

- From inside `B`, open it in a new tab with `<C-w>T`.
  The problem is that destroys the `B` window in `tab1`.
- `tabe <full path to filename>` - this works, but I am trying to find a "shortcut"

#### What I have tried using ctrlp

- `<C-p>`, type in few characters of filename, `<C-t>`

Unfortunately ctrlp excludes the current buffer from its results, I know I can move to another window, buy I always forget this when I am coding, so I just assume ctrlp cant find the file and resort to some other way to open the file.
Is there a shortcut to open a file in a new tab, leaving the current one intact or to enable ctrlp to include the current buffer in its results?

Answer (score 11):

`:tab split` will create a new tab displaying the current buffer, since `:tab` modifies any command that would normally create a split to instead create a tab page.

If you want to override `<C-w>T` to do that instead of its default behavior, you can remap it.

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-w>T :tab split<CR>
```

---

You may be wondering why I used `:tab split` instead of `:tabedit %`.  According to the documentation, `:tabedit {file}` is just like creating a new tab and then running `:edit {file}`.

Therefore, it would be a bad idea to use since `:edit {file}` on a modified buffer would try to reload the buffer.  `:tab split` better fits the behavior you're describing of just opening a new view of the existing buffer.

All that being said, the implementation of `:tabedit {file}` apparently doesn't act *just* like `:edit {file}` since it doesn't actually reload the buffer.

Comment: Ah very cool, I just  tested now, yes so - if you wanted to open the current buffer in a new tab using `:tabe %`, but the buffer *had unsaved changes* - vim blocks the action and throws `E:37 no write change - add ! to override`

Answer (score 8):

After some research I found a solution.
If you are focused on the buffer/window:

```
:tabe %
```

This opens the current buffer in new tab and leaves the current window intact.
*why* does it leave the old buffer intact when `<C-w>T` destroys it? I guess its because `tabe` generally *creates* a new tab, whereas `<C-w>T` seems to create a new tab and *move* the current window and buffer to it.

Answer (score 3):

Another way, just for the fun of it…

```
:tabnew|b#
```

- create a new tab page, containing a new window, containing a new empty buffer.
- then switch to the "alternate file".